# GLSL variables not storing?

Tags: variables, unity-game-engine, glsl, shader

I am learning GLSL through Unity and I recently came across a problem involving the storing of variables.

Shader "Shader" {

```
Properties{
    _Hole_Position("hole_Position", Vector) = (0., 0., 0., 1.0)
    _Hole_EventHorizonDistance("hole_EventHorizonDistance", Float) = 1.0
    _DebugValue("debugValue", Float) = 0.0
}
SubShader{
    Pass{
    GLSLPROGRAM
    uniform mat4 _Object2World;
//Variables
varying float debugValue;

varying vec4 pos;
varying vec4 hole_Position;
varying float hole_EventHorizonDistance = 1;
#ifdef VERTEX
void main()
{
    pos = _Object2World * gl_Vertex;
    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
}
#endif
#ifdef FRAGMENT
void main()
{
    float dist = distance(vec4(pos.x, 0.0,pos.z, 1.0), vec4(hole_Position.x, 0.0, hole_Position.z, 1.0));
    debugValue = dist;
    if (dist < hole_EventHorizonDistance)
    {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1.0);
    }
    else
    {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(0.4, 0.6, 1.0, 1.0);
    }
    //gl_FragColor = vec4(hole_EventHorizonDistance, 0, 0, 1.0);
}
#endif
ENDGLSL
}
}
}
```

Now Hole_Position and EventHorizonDistance are changed from an outside C#-script with:

```
g.GetComponent<Renderer>().sharedMaterial.SetVector("_Hole_Position", new Vector4(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z, 1));
g.GetComponent<Renderer>().sharedMaterial.SetFloat("_Hole_EventHorizonDistance", 2);
```

this does not work as I intend it too (by changing the fragments color if its position is within 2 units from Hole_Position. However debugging with:

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(hole_EventHorizonDistance, 0, 0, 1.0);
```

seemingly suggests that EventHorizon is 0 at all times (the mesh tested on remains completely black), however debugging by getting and printing the variable from an outside (via

```
 print(g.GetComponent<Renderer>().sharedMaterial.GetFloat("_Hole_EventHorizonDistance"));
```

) tells me EventHorizonDistance = 2. I cannot wrap my head around why this is the case, why is it so?

Comment: I don't know about how this is in GLSL, but in CG the variables you want to set via properties have to have the same name, so your varying float should also be named _Hole_EventHorizonDistance

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either, through the variable is seemingly able to be changed from within the GLSL-script without any problems at all.